# question on $\zeta(0.5 + 14.134725142i)$

Tags: numerical-methods, riemann-zeta

I did the computation of the first zero and I am getting the following:

$\zeta(0.5 + 14.134725142i) = 5.791088565628443e-05 + 0.0021057049170408624i$

Should the precision of the zero be much higher?

Thanks

Comment: "I did the computation of the first zero..." - where? "should the precision of the zero be much higher" - well, the better an approximation you have, the smaller the value of $\zeta$ will be. That said, on *Mathematica* I get $\approx -3.308529499333227\times10^{-11} + 2.0781435075213475\times10^{-10}i$.

Comment: I did the computation on my mac, if that is what you are asking.. you are right. when I took 1.0e7 terms, I get both real and imag with exponent 1.0e-5.

Comment: Well, that's only part of the information that might be useful; what program did you use?

Comment: I wrote a python program.

Comment: Then it is possible that your Python program is not working too well for complex evaluations. (These are details you should have put in your question to begin with.) Without seeing what your program does, it's hard to say anything. [In any case...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Zeta%5B1%2F2+%2B+I+14.134725142%5D)

Comment: Can you also compute $\zeta'$ at that point? That will give you an idea of the size of the error you should expect.

Comment: (and by computing the derivative, do not use a finite-difference approximation blindly, as that contributes numerical errors of its own.)

Comment: Thank you.. Everything is working as expected. Reason I wrote it myself was I could play around with stuff and plot things.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician. *blindly* is a good word; I just made a central difference calculation at $x=0.3456+12.987i$ using $h=x\times 10^{-6}$ and obtained a "good" value.

Comment: @Claude, yes, you got my intent; you need some cleverness like central differences + [choosing a good step size](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=M9hTn3UAheQC&pg=PA219). Or, Richardsonian extrapolation, but this is more expensive (and computing $\zeta$ is certainly expensive!).